# Matrix expression parser/engine

Tags: java, parsing, math, matrix

I am looking for a matrix expression parser/engine. For example,

```
3 * A + B * C
```

where A, B, C are matrices is a typical expression. This should be similar to (single value) math expression parser/engine but should handle matrix value and variable. I've already googled in vain. I am also willing to modify existing math expression parser but I am not sure how I can go about it. So if you can give me any clue or hint, I will appreciate it.

Comment: There's [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) for basic linear algebra. Or are you specifically looking for a scripting-like syntax like `3 * A + B * C`?

Comment: In a work project we used [Jep](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jep/) to parse and evaluate maths expressions. We didn't need to support matrices, but it should still be able to hand just the parsing, you can evaluate the expression tree yourself.

Comment: @Paul: Not really, we let the library evaluate things, which it can do for scalars and vectors. (Unfortunately, not matrices.) You'll have to poke around the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer on [how to build simple parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2336769/120163).  This especially suited for expression parsers.

It is pretty easy to modify such a parser to compute the answer as it parses. Just add an action routine whenever the parser recognizes syntax, to do what the syntax says.

Comment: Building this kind of parser is **so** easy that trying to tear up another one simply isn't worth the trouble. If you have much more complex parsing requirements, or you have to graft your new expression syntax in another one, then you have to worry about how to do that graft. And for that, the only advice you're likely to get is, "well, it depends on how that other parser is structured", which is pretty useless advice.  If the problem is simply to change the other parser to evaluate the expression differently, well, then you have to change its evaluation code :-} Agreed, likely not hard.